# how to open modal from another modal in ui bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

**i want to open a another modal by clicking on "open me link"**

the code and snippet are provided below.

[image: modal image]

**script.js**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap','angular-drawer']);
```

angular.module('myApp').controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $log) {
    $scope.open = function () {

```
    $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        backdrop: true,
        windowClass: 'modal',
        controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance, $log, user) {
            $scope.user = user;
            $scope.submit = function () {
                $log.log('Submiting user info.');
                $log.log(user);
                $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            }
            $scope.cancel = function () {
                $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };
        },
        resolve: {
            user: function () {
                return $scope.user;
            }
        }
    });
};


$scope.open1 = function () {

    $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent1.html',
        backdrop: true,
        windowClass: 'modal',
        controller: function ($scope,open, $modalInstance, $log, user) {
            $scope.opensignup=function () {

                $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };
            $scope.user = user;
            $scope.submit = function () {
                $log.log('Submiting user info.');
                $log.log(user);
                $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            }
            $scope.cancel11 = function () {
                $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };
        },
        resolve: {
            user: function () {
                return $scope.user;
            }
        }
    });
};
```

});

**html**

```
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <h3>I'm a modal!</h3>
      </div>
      <form ng-submit="submit()">
          <div class="modal-body">
              <label>User name</label>
              <input type="text" ng-model="user.user" />
              <label>Password</label>
              <input type="password" ng-model="user.password" />
          </div>
          <a ng-click="opensignup()">Open me!</a>
          <div class="modal-footer">
              <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel11()">Cancel</button>
              <input type="submit" class="btn primary-btn" value="Submit" />
          </div>
      </form>
  </script>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent1.html">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <h3>I'm a modal11111111111111111111111!</h3>
      </div>
      <form ng-submit="submit()">
          <div class="modal-body">
              <label>User name</label>
              <input type="text" ng-model="user.user" />
              <label>Password</label>
              <input type="password" ng-model="user.password" />
          </div>
          <button class="btn" ng-click="cancel()">Open me!</button>
          <div class="modal-footer">
              <a class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</a>
              <input type="submit" class="btn primary-btn" value="Submit" />
          </div>
      </form>
  </script>

  <button class="btn" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
```

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals says: multiple open modals isn't supported

Comment: great.. you described whet you want to do, but gave no indication of problems you are having , or any code. What is the specific issue you are having?

Comment: if you need, for example, to change from modal "login" to modal "forgot password", you can to use ng-if/ng-show/ng-hide in some blocks, in the same modal, or to close current modal and open the next modal.

Comment: is not there a way to accomplish this? i want that by clicking on" open me "  link signup page open in modal @JoaozitoPolo

Comment: is not there a way to accomplish this? i want that by clicking on" open me " link signup page open in modal @charlietfl

Comment: well... you can... to create your own second modal, using css (a div with position relative, with a inner div with position absolute and high zorder)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this :

in your controller :(with $modal injected in your controller)

```
  $scope.openLogin = function () {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'login.html',
            controller: $scope.modalLogin
        });
    }

    $scope.modalLogin = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
        //edit to close modal login
        $scope.modalLoginInstance = $modalInstance;
        $scope.cancelLogin = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        }
    }

    $scope.login = function () {
        //Your code to login

    }

    $scope.openMe = function(){
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'openMe.html',
            controller: $scope.modalOpenMe
        });
    }

    $scope.modalOpenMe = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
        //edit to close modal login
        $scope.modalLoginInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        $scope.cancelOpenMe = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        }
    }
```

In your html for login:

```
<div ng-controller="YourController">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" ng-click="cancelLogin()"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h2 class="modal-title">Your Title</h2>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    //your login form
    //For link openMe bind method openMe with ng-click
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    //your footer
</div>
```

create your template openMe.
I use something like this for my application and I can open the secondary modal above the primary modal.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: jonathan thanks for the answer... everything working fine but when i calling cancelLogin in modalopenMe controller... "nothing happens".
can you help me to how to call the cancelLogin function .

Comment: Look the edit, I changed the code to close the modal. You put the $modalInstance of modal login in a scope and you call the method dismiss in the openMe method. Have a nice day